# pyqt QDoubleSpinBox adjusts always to integer

Tags: pyqt, qt4.8, qspinbox

I'm using pyqt and have two QDoubleSpinBoxes which I use to define intervals. Typically those intervals are integer, e.g. degree Celsius. Depending on the use case I switch the range, stepsize, unit, etc. One case involves voltage and needs to be decimal, so I always use QDoubleSpinBox but reduce decimals and stepsize to correspond to integers. Here is a snippet for the voltage case:

```
    self.to_spin.setDecimals(2)
    self.from_spin.setDecimals(2)
    self.to_spin.setSuffix(" V")
    self.from_spin.setSuffix(" V")
    self.to_spin.setSingleStep(0.1)
    self.from_spin.setSingleStep(0.1)
    self.to_spin.setRange(0.0,40.0)
    self.from_spin.setRange(0.0,40.0)
    if set_defaults:
        self.from_spin.setValue(2.0)
        self.to_spin.setValue(18.0)
```

The Problem is, that even in the Scenario above the values entered are always corrected to the nearest integer.
I use QDoubleSpinBoxes in a different place but without varying the intervals, etc. and there it is working as it should be.

Any suggestions? The validator should be okay because it's a DoubleBox, right?
Any help is appreciated - thanks in advance,

Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime, I believe, I found out what the problem were: if one of the values used to define range, stepsize and so on is integer, the entered value jumps to integer as well. Anyway, now it works.